# If intellisense shows a HasValue property, does it mean the type is nullable?

Tags: c#, nullable

In our `ADO` framework code base I find this definition:

```
// Reference_System_RTK 
public Company.Framework.Data.DbTypes.DbString Reference_System_RTKField 
{ 
    get {return this.DbString("Reference_System_RTK");} 
    set {this.DbString("Reference_System_RTK", value);} 
}
```

And in the code when I want to read its value, I also see `.Value` and `.HasValue` in the intellisense suggestions.
So my question is when intellisense is showing these properties does it always mean that it has been a `null able type`? So I should always its `HasValue and .Value` for getting its value? I can't just reference the field name?

```
        PrimaryKeysCrossReferenceTable.PrimaryKeysCrossReferenceDataRow tempDataRow = tblPrimaryKeysCrossReference.Rows[0] as PrimaryKeysCrossReferenceTable.PrimaryKeysCrossReferenceDataRow;
        if (tempDataRow != null && tempDataRow.Reference_System_RTKField.HasValue)
            result = tempDataRow.Reference_System_RTKField.Value;
```

vs

```
result = tempDataRow.Reference_System_RTKField;
```

I don't get compilation error for any of them. 
I also looked at the Table column definitions in `SQL Server` and for that field it says `"not null"`

Comment: It could be nullable, or it could be a type that happens to have a `Value` and `HasValue` properties. You'll have to look at the type to find out. What  type does `DbString()` return? What type is `result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact possible for types other than `Nullable` to have a `Value` and `HasValue` properties, so no, just because a type has those properties doesn't mean that it's an instance of `Nullable`.

Comment: I also looked at the Table column definitions in SQL Server and for that field it says "not null" , so do you think which way should I get the value of this field?

Comment: @Blake Why don't you experiment with a few options and see what does and doesn't work.

Comment: Project isn't at a state that I can run it and test now.

Comment: Hmm, now in source code I saw that other people when then wanted to "assign" values to this field they have not assigned it to its .Value ... so I think the second method of reading its value is fine, I mean without checking .Value